# How can I quickly unlock a Windows 7 machine remotely?

Tags: windows-7, synergy

I have two Windows 7 machines connected with Synergy. When I want to lock or unlock the machines, I have to do so twice, and it would be nice to only have one keyboard and mouse at my desk. Is there a script or program I can run from the server machine to lock and unlock the client machine? I've tried `telnet` with `tscon`, and I've tried `psexec` to run `tscon`. I can run `cmd` within a remote desktop session to call `tscon`, but that's unwieldy. If I elevate Synergy on the client, my Ctrl-Alt-Delete keystrokes only go to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + Del only works for the server, BUT! you can use Ctrl+Alt+Pause/Break to send to the client, where it will emulate CAD

also you *might* have just solved my issue by accident too.